# How to automatically add a header to every new TestComplete JScript unit?

Tags: testcomplete

I would like to automatically add the user details and few other items as a header in every new script created by the user. For example:

```
/********************************************
Author : xxxxxx
Date Created : mm/dd/yyyy
*********************************************/
```

Is this possible in TestComplete?

Comment: As @Dmitry said, this is currently not possible, but you can [submit a feature request](http://community.smartbear.com/t5/TestComplete-Feature-Requests/idb-p/TestXCompleteFeatureRequests).

Answer (score 0):

TestComplete does not allow doing this. However, you can create a small script test that will put this text to the Clipboard. So, before creating a new script unit, you need to run this simple test and then just insert the content of the Clipboard to the newly created unit.

```
function generateHeader()
{
  var header =
    "/********************************************\r\n" +
    "Author : Ganesh Kumar Palanisamy\r\n" +
    "Date Created : " + aqConvert.DateTimeToFormatStr(aqDateTime.Now(), "%m/%d/%Y") + "\r\n" +
    "*********************************************/\r\n\r\n";
  Sys.Clipboard = header;
}
```

Comment: `before creating a new script unit, you need to run this simple test`: Or one could make this code a toolbar button in TestComplete (via script extensions).

Answer (score 0):

I would say, code templates will be easier though not customized for every user here. Just create a template in

```
Tools -> Options -> Panels -> Code Editor -> Code Template
```

with details needed and press `Ctrl+J` every time you create an unit.